# Word 2010 - Shading paragraph background

Tags: microsoft-word

I have created a new Word 2010 document and am wanting to set the background shading of a paragraph to a given colour (using the blue circled button).

My issue is that when I have done so, the areas to the left of the bullet points (shown in red) do not highlight. How can I cause that area to be set to the paragraph background colour as well?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The background colour only affects the actual text and paragraph (which the gutter on the left of the bullet points is not technically a part of).

You'll probably have to wrap the block you want shaded in a table cell and then use Borders and Shading to set the background colour for the entire cell.

Comment: Thank you - appreciate your help, sadly I can't rate your comment us as yet. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the issue is in the very next tool, "Borders and Shading".

1. From the drop-down menu choose "Borders and Shading..."
2. Click the "Shading" tab
3. Choose the desired "Fill color"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for commenting, however the original answer still stands as it is the only correct one, yours still exhibits the same problem as the question asks.

Comment: It is a tremendous answer!

Answer (score 1):

The only other way to do it, is to reduce the indent of the bullet point so that it lines up with the text. You can do this by going to Page Layout > Put your cursor on the bullet > Reduce the Left Indent.