# How to format all of the whitespace on a Paragraph in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I've typed up an email with some text, then an indented bullet list with a few sub-bullets and a few more paragraphs. Here's a screencap of "part" of it.

[image]

Here's what I've done:

- Highlight 6 lines with bullet points + the indented paragraphs
- Click the `Format Text` option at the top of the New Email window
- Select the Paint Bucket tool on the Paragraph section of the ribbon and pick a color

This only paints the portion of the email with actual text, excluding the whitespace to the left.

Is there a way I can force it to color the entire line, rather than just the portions that have stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing on the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/288996/word-2010-shading-paragraph-background), you can't do this using the paint bucket tool. You can instead do this by putting your text inside a single-celled table, then shading that cell with the background color you want.

I achieve this by selecting the lines I wanted shaded, going to the `Insert` ribbon, choosing `Table` then `Insert Table`. Right-click on the table and select `Merge Cells`, then right-click again and select `Borders and Shading`.

In the `Borders` tab, choose `None`. In the `Shading` tab, use the `Fill` drop-down to choose the color you want.

Here's what it looked like for me, after selecting only a portion of my text:

[image]